# How to make Add to cart By id In VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, e-commerce

I've been facing a problem whilst I'm working with a eCommerce demo file with VueJs. I have add all the required code but when I click on Add To Cart option in a same file, the product shown like below-[The Problem I'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXP02.jpg)

Comment: From Review: You stated something that you wanted to do. But you haven't actually asked a question. Have you tried to accomplish your goal? What prevented you from accomplishing it? Can you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example showing your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the quantity to increase instead of adding a new item. Wherever the logic is that adds a new item, first loop through the cart and check if the matching item already exists. If it does, increment the quantity by one. If not, add a new item.

Can't help much more than that without details.